# For loop with iframe in html, spotify play button

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to make a for loop that displays the Spotify play button for every URI I put in a specific list. So if this album `spotify:album:08Cq2FeFxRQdpkKrjCGrth` was in the list it would display as

```
<iframe src="https://open.spotify.com/embed/album/08Cq2FeFxRQdpkKrjCGrth" width="300" height="380" frameborder="0" allowtransparency="true" allow="encrypted-media"></iframe>
```

So the for loop would put the URI in the `iframe` tag.

Here is the following code I have, I have already looked at many tutorials and examples online but can't figure it out for this type of situation.

```
var list = ["spotify:album:08Cq2FeFxRQdpkKrjCGrth"];
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var source = list[i].split(":")[2];
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.src = source;
    iframe.width = "300";
    iframe.height = "380";
    iframe.frameborder = "0";
    iframe.allowtransparency = "true";
    iframe.allow = "encrypted-media";
    document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(iframe);
}
```

Comment: what is the current problem you are getting with this?

Comment: Have you actually tested if this URI will be rendered in an iframe? I don't see any protocol, host, stc.  (i.e.` h++ps://host.top/path`)

Comment: I am trying to make a for-loop that uses an array of URI's(which are spotify albums) such as "spotify:album:08Cq2FeFxRQdpkKrjCGrth") so it dispalys evevry album I put in the array, so how could i fix or add to my code to get it to display the album(s) with the iframe tag.

Comment: You are setting the album ID as the `src` without `https://open.spotify.com/embed/album/`

Answer (score 0):

here is what i came upp with. but you need to deploy this to a server to work, or u get this error no matter what even if u add a sandbox. this need to be deployed to a server with a proper http/https url(no local or ipaddress url will work)

```
embed.2019-01-15_bcdc2b81.js:1 Uncaught DOMException: Failed to read the 'cookie' property from 'Document': The document is sandboxed and lacks the
```

```js
var list = ["spotify:album:1DFixLWuPkv3KT3TnV35m3"];
var url = "https://embed.spotify.com?uri="
for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
    var source =url + list[i]
    var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
    iframe.src = source;
    iframe.width = "300";
    iframe.height = "380";
    iframe.frameborder = "0";
    iframe.allowtransparency = "true";
    iframe.allow = "encrypted-media";
    document.getElementById("demo").appendChild(iframe);
    
}
```

```css
iframe{
border:1px solid red;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```